# upper bound on cross entropy or relative entropy

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, information-theory, upper-lower-bounds, information-geometry

Am looking for upper bounds for relative-entropy or cross-entropy for non-gaussian case . All I am aware of is bounds for entropy based on determinant of covariance matrix.

What about for relative entropy?

Answer (score 2):

As the other commenter already stated, the KL-divergence aka relative entropy is not bounded.

As the cross entropy $H(p,q)$ can be written as
$$H(p,q) = H(p) + D_{KL}(p||q)$$

it is therefore also not bounded.

Answer (score 1):

There is no upper (unrestricted) bound of relative entropy.
See eg [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/323069/can-kl-divergence-ever-be-greater-than-1).

There are some upper bounds in terms of some features of the distributions. See eg [here](https://ejde.math.txstate.edu/Volumes/2016/237/popescu.pdf) , [here](https://hrcak.srce.hr/file/149467) or [here](http://www.m-hikari.com/ams/ams-2011/ams-65-68-2011/sayyarehAMS65-68-2011.pdf).